# If two very small and smooth particles collide at perfect right angles, is there friction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, friction

If two perfectly round particles collide at perfect right angles, is there friction between them?

If so, Is the friction in the form of heat (average kinetic motion), because if it is, where is this heat.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrangement is such that the particles approach their collective center of mass without any angular momentum (in the COM frame) then no friction is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Size doesn't matter and smoothness only matters depending on how you're measuring the friction. Overall if one surface causes another surface to move or change direction at all then that is resistance. In that case there will be a change in momentum and a release of heat in the form of radiation. Remember when you accelerate electrons they emit photons.